# Can I create a fixed grid with singularity?

Tags: singularitygs

Last week I discovered the Compass grid **Singularity**, which is impressing.
I'm going to design my next project based on Singularity.
Unfortunately I need to use a fixed grid (width=1024px).

Is it possible to design a fixed grid with Singularity?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Singularity works a little bit differently than other grid systems in that it only concerns itself with the grid and not the container. If you'd like a fixed container, simply add `width: 1024px;` to whatever your container class is, and you'll have a fixed width container.

Answer (score 1):

You’re in luck because yes it is possible!

Just set `width: 1024px;` on whatever element contains your columns:

HTML:

  `<div class="container">
    <article>stuff</article>
    <aside>stuff</aside>
  </div>`

Sass:

  `.container {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }`

Your markup may be different, but that is one solution.